# function on a fixed length sequence of positive real number that induces lexicographic order

Tags: sequences-and-series, functional-analysis, functions, discrete-mathematics

Let $S$ be the finite set of sequences of length $n$, whose entries are all real positive numbers. Can we define a function $f$ on $S$ such that the order $f$ induces on $S$ i.e $\le$ is the same as the lexicographic order of sequences in $S$.

Comment: Let me be sure: if $\Bbb R_+$ is the set of positive real numbers, and $\preceq$ is lexicographic order on $S=\Bbb R_+^n$, you’re asking whether there is a function $f:S\to\Bbb R$ such that $f(s)<f(t)$ if and only if $s\prec t$?

Comment: @BrianM.Scott, ya that is what I meant.

Answer (score 1):

HINT: There obviously is if $n=1$, so assume that $n\ge 2$. In fact, let’s look at the simplest interesting case, $n=2$. For each $x\in\Bbb R_+$ let $I_x=\{x\}\times(0,1)$. Then $\{I_x:x\in\Bbb R_+\}$ is an uncountable family of pairwise disjoint open intervals in $\langle S,\preceq\rangle$, where $\preceq$ is the lexicographic order on $S$. Does $\Bbb R$ contain such a family of intervals? Can this idea be generalize to all $n\ge 2$?